# Ada : Float literals vs float variables

Tags: floating-point, rounding, ada, division, calculation

I am seeing some strange behaviour when rounding floating point numbers in my Ada code.

I understand that floats are not reliable, and that sometimes they aren't represented exactly.

My question is around why it would matter if you store the value in a variable first.

```
float'rounding(8.9 / 0.2)
```

the above comes out as ***45***, which seems to make sense, ***8.9 / 0.2 = 44.5*** then round away from zero.
(I also tried casting each number to a float to make sure there wasnt some type difference)

but then

```
a : float : 8.9;
b : float : 0.2;
float'rounding(a / b)
```

this time it comes out as ***44***. which means that ***a / b = 44.4999999*** then round down.

Why does saving the values in a variable change the outcome of the calculation when its all the same types?!

Any insight would be amazing!

Comment: At least in  C, `8.9, 0.2, 8.9 / 0.2` are `double` precision and `a / b` is single and so slightly different quotients,.  Not sure if that applies to Ada.

Comment: @chux Yeah I thought it could be something like that. which is why I tried
```float(8.9) / float(0.2)``` and still got 44.5

Comment: @TheIronDuckling I don't know ADA but in C++ (and in C with a similar cast) `float(8.9)/float(0.2)` involves [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding): 8.9 to double precision then single, so the result might be different from `8.9f/0.2f` where the literals are rounded to single precision directly

Answer (score 3):

Ada real literals are of the type universal_real and may be used in calculations involving an real type, such as float or long_float as long as the literal value is within the range of valid values for the type.

Universal_real is implemented as the "largest" type representable by the computer floating point hardware. This is similar to the C language where real literals are double precision.

See the following example:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   a_val : constant := 8.9;
   b_val : constant := 0.2;
   a     : float := a_val;
   b     : float := b_val;
   a_l   : long_float := a_val;
   b_l   : long_float := b_val;
begin
   Put_Line(Float'Image(Float'Rounding(a_val / b_val)));
   Put_Line(Float'Image(Float'Rounding(a / b)));
   Put_Line(Long_Float'Image(Long_Float'Rounding(a_l / b_l)));
end Main;
```

The named numbers a_val and b_val are of the type universal_real. The output of the program is:

```
 4.50000E+01
 4.40000E+01
 4.50000000000000E+01
```

The division when directly using the name numbers is identical to the division when using long_float, and different than the division using float.

Comment: Static real expressions such as `8.9 / 0.2` are evaluated by the compiler exactly, typically using an unbounded rational-number ("big real") package [ARM 4.9 (33)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-9.html).

Comment: This is what I was suspecting, so I made the change to ```float'rounding(float(8.9) / float(0.2))``` and got the same 45 answer. Either way, ill put it down to the 32 bit-ness of the single precision floats. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ada, but most of those numbers can't be represented accurately as (binary) floating point numbers.  Jeffrey pointed out that the difference is due to your calculation being performed exactly at compile time, but thought it might be instructive to show why the runtime version gives the "wrong" answer.

Using [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) representation, i.e. `float` variables in Ada, we get:

```
input       nearest representable float
8.9       =  8.8999996185302734375
0.2       =  0.20000000298023223876953125
8.9 / 0.2 = 44.499996185302734375
```

rounding the result works as expected mathematically, but due to the previous loss of precision you end up with 44.

For comparison, with [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floats, i.e. `long_float` in Ada, it happens to go the other way:

```
8.9       =  8.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625
0.2       =  0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
8.9 / 0.2 = 44.5
```

the errors happened to cancel during division hence the exact result of 44.5, the rounding of this goes the expected way.

I tend to use the Python REPL for quickly checking these interactively, the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is especially useful for seeing the expansion of floats.  Python only knows about binary64 floats natively, but the NumPy library provides access to other [floating-point types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#floating-point-types).